# Enable only 1 of 2 Swing checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcheckbox

I have 2 checkboxes (A & B) declared with `JCheckBox`.

Is there any way to disable a checkbox B if checkbox A is checked and vice versa? If I check checkbox B, checkbox A should be disabled using AWT Swing.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So you want the functionality of a radio button, on a checkbox... ?

Comment: yes. I want only one checkbox to be selected at a time among the two

Answer (score 4):

Add the check boxes to a [`ButtonGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html):

> This class is used to create a *multiple-exclusion scope for a set of buttons.* Creating a set of buttons with the same `ButtonGroup` object means that *turning "on" one of those buttons turns off all other buttons in the group.*

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my concern is I have to only use checkboxes instead of radio buttons. Please help.

Comment: *"But my concern is.."* ..a concern that could be put to rest by either 1) Consulting the documentation (while understanding it) - estimated time: 3 minutes. ***or*** 2) Trying it! - esitmated time: 1 minute.